# Groupping in Gauge Panel, possible?

Tags: pointers, reporting-services, diagram

i am currently trying to Group Values given to Pointers in a Gauge Panel.

The Scenario Looks like this:

[image: GaugePanel]

Now i have a dataset with the following Fields:

**KPIName**

**KPIValue**

I have all the Values in KPIValue, and I Group them with the field KPIName since i currently have 4 different KPIValues.
What i want to accomplish now is to put in **4 different Pointers** in my GaugePanel and let them Show each KPIValue, meaning I want them to be **Grouped**, or at least let each pointer **individually be Filtered** to the KPIName it is supposed to Show.

I am working with GaugePanels for the first time, but it doesn't really seem possible to me for now,

Is there a solution ?
Is there a way ?

Or at least a Workaround ? (like adding custom fields to the Data Set, which are filtered by KPIName, or something similiar ?)

Thanks a lot for your Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the expression for the pointers to

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!KPI.Value = "KPI1", Fields!Value.Value, 0))

=Sum(IIf(Fields!KPI.Value = "KPI2", Fields!Value.Value, 0))

=Sum(IIf(Fields!KPI.Value = "KPI3", Fields!Value.Value, 0))

 ...
```

[image]